# Changing the stride of a pointer increment

Tags: c++

I currently have a class like this:

```
struct Rgb
{
  static const int NUM_CHANNELS = 3;
  unsigned char channel[NUM_CHANNELS];
};
```

which is never instantiated but is used to determine the stride of a pointer increment.

I wanted to allow this stride to change based on some runtime information. Will something like this work?

```
#include <iostream>

class Rgb
{
public:
  static int* Channel;
  static void SetChannelSize(unsigned int channelSize)
  {
    Channel = new int(channelSize);
  }
};

int main()
{

  int numbers[1000];
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
    numbers[i] = i;
    }

  Rgb::SetChannelSize(3);

  Rgb* rgbNnumbers = reinterpret_cast<Rgb*>(numbers);

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    std::cout << rgbNnumbers[i] << std::endl; //error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << *(rgbNnumbers + ((unsigned int)i))’

    }

  return 0;
}
```

(I wasn't sure how to step over the demo array I setup in this example to test it out).

Any comments?

Comment: You have conflicting type declarations in your code.

Comment: The day the compiler decides to use 8-byte struct alignment is the day this scheme mysteriously breaks in a hard-to-diagnose way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `[i]` is a compile-time operation, it will simply not work for element sizes that are not known at compile-time. You must increment the pointer yourself with arithmetic.

But that being said, most likely you actually know the size of the element at compile-time. You are probably writing specific code for 24-bit and 32-bit (et al) pixel depths, so you should still be able to use brackets to dereference. Just organize your code to use the right class (`Rgb32`, `Rgb565`, `Rgb24`, etc).

Regarding your compiler error, iostream doesn't know how to convert a `Rgb` to a `string`, so you naturally get this error. I would suggest creating a `Rgb::ToString()` function.

Comment: +1: And to avoid rewriting your code for different RGB types you can use templates.

Answer (score 0):

I presume by "stride of a pointer increment" you're talking about the number of "bytes" by which the pointer is incremented.

If that's the case, then the short answer is "no".  In your second example, the class is simply a naming scope, because there are no instance members.  You won't be able to create an instance of it, so no such pointer increment will be able to occur.

The only way I can think of to modify the quantity by which an increment increases the pointer value is to define a smart pointer class and an operator++() on that smart pointer.  But even then I'm not sure it'll get you what you want, because I honestly can't figure out what you're trying to do.  It looks like maybe you're trying to be clever in interpreting/unpacking/decoding a chunk of memory, but that could be way off base.

Answer (score 0):

If the stride is settled at initialization time and it isn't changed
thereafter, some array-like class like the following might meet your
purpose:

```
#include <vector>

struct Rgb
{
  unsigned char channel[1];
};

struct RgbArray
{
  unsigned int channelSize;
  std::vector< Rgb > Channel;
  RgbArray( unsigned int channelSize, unsigned int elementCount )
    : channelSize( channelSize ), Channel( channelSize * elementCount ) {}
  Rgb& operator[]( size_t i ) { return Channel[ i * channelSize ]; }
};

int main() {
  int channelSize = 3;
  RgbArray rgb( channelSize, 2 );
  rgb[0].channel[0] = 1;
  rgb[0].channel[1] = 2;
  rgb[0].channel[2] = 3;
}
```

As this code is improvised one for an illustrative purpose,
if some elements will be added to the array after its initialization,
proper improvements will be needed.

Hope this helps